# Are there any AvP stories that leave out humans?

Tags: aliens, alien-vs.-predator

In both Alien vs Predator movies, as well as any of the comics I've seen, humans get caught between the battles between the xenomorophs and Yajuta (predator species). Does anyone know of examples of predator/alien clashes that don't feature humans getting dragged into the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Aliens vs Predator: Blood Time](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Aliens_vs._Predator:_Blood_Time)* is a short story in comic book format that ties the events of *[Aliens vs Predator (1990 series)](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Aliens_vs._Predator_(1990_comic_series))* and *Aliens vs Predator: War*.  Aspects introduced in *Blood Time* (ie, the clan leader Top Knot) ease the reader into the first issue of *War*.

**Aliens vs Predator: Blood Time has only Predators and Aliens, no Humans, plus a plot; albeit Predator-focused.**

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and no. Although there are *individual confrontations* that take place solely between the Yajuta and the Xenomorphs, humans play a sizeable part in every licensed property in the [Aliens Vs Predator franchise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_vs._Predator), with the main (human) participants usually being either Colonial Marines or civilian cannon-fodder.

That being said, I was able to identify at least one property within the franchise that contains **zero** humans; the 1993 Gameboy game "[Alien VS Predator: The Last Of His Clan](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_vs_Predator:_The_Last_of_His_Clan)". The intro notes that it takes place on a planet where all of the (human) colonists are long since dead.